# Make nginx deny all browser requests except from specific IPs

Tags: nginx

How to configure nginx to deny all browser requests except from specific IPs?

The nginx must serve only non browser requests and browser requests from specific IPs

Comment: Downvoting for not showing that you've tried to figure this out on your own.

Comment: Strange idea. What the reason? What have you tried? How will you distinguish non-browser from browser?

Comment: i have tried checking "http_user_agent"  check it was for working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
map $remote_addr $whitelist {
    default                     1;
    ~^(192.168.123.*)$          0;
}
```

[...]

```
location / {
    if ($whitelist) { return 404; }
}
```

:: with in map, if $remote_addr matches the second line the variable $whitelist will become 0, else 1

:: with in location, if the variable $whitelist equals 1 or higher the client will be denied access with a 404 (in this case it is 1 when no match is made with the example ip wildcard or zero when it does allowing access)

For doing this with user agents:

```
map $http_user_agent $whitelist {
    default              0;
    ~*Unknown.*Client    1;
}
```

:: note the reversed result values (0 and 1)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what is going on.

Comment: My configuration: 
`location / {
        set $agent  0;
   
  #Allowing specific IP set
  deny **.*.**.***;
  allow **.**.**.***;
        deny all;
  
  #Non browser hit check
  if ($http_user_agent !~* "Mozilla|Chrome") {
               root   /usr/local/AdminUI/;
               set $agent 1;
     }
  
  if ($agent = 0) { 
                return 403;
        }`
  
Individually this checks are working fine,But nginx is not allowing to try `allow <ipaddress>` inside if block or two `root /usr/local/AdminUI/;` inside "Location"

Comment: i want to allow all hits from mobile app (non browser) which will not have any http_user_agent